# Isomorphism between $Pic_X[2]$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{2g}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ a Riemann surface of genus $g$. How could I prove that there is an isomorphism between $Pic_X[2]$ (i.e the line bundles $L$ such as $L^2 \simeq \mathcal{O}_X $) and $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{2g}$?

I know that, because of the Weil's Reciprocity Law, we can define the following Weil pairing

$Pic_X[2] \times Pic_X[2] \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$,

but I don't know if it could be useful.

Comment: The Jacobian variety $J(X)$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_variety) is a complex torus of dimension $g$ parametrising degree-0 line bundles on $X$, and $Pic_X[2]$ is the 2-torsion subgroup of $J(X)$. It's not hard to check that any complex torus of dimension $g$ has 2-torsion subgroup isomorphic to $(\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z)^{2g}$.

Comment: Thank you Asal. The last thing: do you know where I can find a proof of this result( that any complex torus of dimension $g$ has $2$-torsion subgroup isomorphic to $(Z/2Z)^{2g}$?

Comment: A complex torus of dimension $g$ is $\mathbf C^g/L$ where $L$ is a lattice. As an abelian group, that is isomorphic to $\mathbf R^{2g}/\mathbf Z^{2g}$. Can you find all the 2-torsion points in that group?